# Performing basic arithmetic in php array

Tags: php, arrays, jquery-easyui

I have a php script which is used to generate information for a jeasyUI Grid.

```
$sql = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT ID, rec_purID, rec_qty, rec_date, p.pur_ID, p.pur_productID, p.pur_supplierID, p.pur_unitPrice, pr.prod_productName, c.cont_fullName FROM receipts inner join purchases p on rec_purID = p.pur_ID inner join products pr on p.pur_productID = pr.prod_productID inner join contacts c on p.pur_supplierID = c.cont_ID")) or SQLError();

while($rec = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $group[] = $rec;
}
foreach ($group as $key => $val) {
    $group[$key]['rec_val'] = $val['rec_qty'] * $val['pur_unitPrice'];
}
$smarty->assign('group', $group);
```

If I print_r this array, it appears to be correct:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [ID] => 78 [rec_purID] => 32 [rec_qty] => 1000 [rec_date] => 2016-03-30 [pur_ID] => 32     [pur_productID] => 5 [pur_supplierID] => 41 [pur_unitPrice] => 100.00 [prod_productName] => Acetate Tow   [cont_fullName] => DELPACK TRADING (PTY) LTD [rec_val] => 100000 ) 
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 79 [rec_purID] => 31 [rec_qty] => 2207 [rec_date] => 2016-03-30 [pur_ID] => 31 [pur_productID] => 5 [pur_supplierID] => 41 [pur_unitPrice] => 95.50 [prod_productName] => Acetate Tow [cont_fullName] => DELPACK TRADING (PTY) LTD [rec_val] => 210768.5 ) 
[2] => Array ( [ID] => 80 [rec_purID] => 31 [rec_qty] => 3000 [rec_date] => 2016-03-31 [pur_ID] => 31 [pur_productID] => 5 [pur_supplierID] => 41 [pur_unitPrice] => 95.50 [prod_productName] => Acetate Tow [cont_fullName] => DELPACK TRADING (PTY) LTD [rec_val] => 286500 )
)
```

My grid, however will never see the value of "rec_val". Please can someone explain where I have gone wrong.

```
<table id="dg" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:100%;height:400px"
                url="receipts.php?do=list" 
                title="Received Goods"
                toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
                iconCls="icon-edit" showFooter="true"
                sortName="ID" sortOrder="asc"
                rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th field="ID" width="10" sortable="true">Internal ID</th>
                       <th field="prod_productName" width="80" sortable="true">Product</th>
                       <th field="cont_fullName" width="80" sortable="true">Supplier</th>
                       <th field="rec_qty" width="80" sortable="true">Quantity</th>
                       <th field="pur_unitPrice" width="80">Unit Price</th>
                       <th field="rec_val" width="80">Value</th>
                       <th field="rec_date" width="80" sortable="true">Date Received</th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

        </table>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The loop looks fine to me. But to be certain you can always dump the resulting `$group` array into a log file.

Comment: Sorry arkascha, I don't know what you mean? I have posted the output above the grid where it shows the contents of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be brackets in one of the names which i guess aren't correctly escaped.

```
DELPACK TRADING (PTY) LTD
```

this closes the array exactly before "rec_val".

I'm not familiar with easyui but i expect this to be the problem especially if the other values do show up correctly.

Comment: I edited the name of that record and removed the () but it does not make any difference.

Comment: It also seems to not be recognized as a string, maybe you need "" around the whole thing? like i said not to familiar with easyui

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the end was to do the calc in the lookup:

```
$row = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT ID, rec_purID, rec_qty, rec_date, p.pur_ID, p.pur_productID, p.pur_supplierID, p.pur_unitPrice, CAST((rec_qty *  p.pur_unitPrice) as UNSIGNED) as rec_value, pr.prod_productName, c.cont_fullName FROM receipts inner join purchases p on rec_purID = p.pur_ID inner join products pr on p.pur_productID = pr.prod_productID inner join contacts c on p.pur_supplierID = c.cont_ID")) or SQLError();
```

> CAST((rec_qty *  p.pur_unitPrice) as UNSIGNED) as rec_value